# Wordpress media section not upload images and not showing images

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

In my  word press site when i try to upload image it is uploaded to uploads folder but not showing in word press backend and also not showing media upload images.

WordPress site contain in sub folder and i access without sub folder directory in URL

[image]

[image]